# Django Dynamic Model, unable to access in admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm using Django 1.11 and I tried to create Django dynamic models by referring this link https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels, by executing each and every step it runs without any issue, but when I see the registered model in the Django admin panel, the Model is visible under it corresponding app, but it not accessible, I don't know what I missed out there.

```
def create_model(name, fields=None, app_label='', module='', options=None, admin_opts=None):
    """
    Create specified model
    """
    class Meta:
        # Using type('Meta', ...) gives a dictproxy error during model creation
        pass

    if app_label:
        # app_label must be set using the Meta inner class
        setattr(Meta, 'app_label', app_label)

    # Update Meta with any options that were provided
    if options is not None:
        for key, value in options.iteritems():
            setattr(Meta, key, value)

    # Set up a dictionary to simulate declarations within a class
    attrs = {'__module__': module, 'Meta': Meta}

    # Add in any fields that were provided
    if fields:
        attrs.update(fields)

    # Create the class, which automatically triggers ModelBase processing
    model = type(name, (models.Model,), attrs)

    # Create an Admin class if admin options were provided
    if admin_opts is not None:
        class Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
            pass
        for key, value in admin_opts:
            setattr(Admin, key, value)
        admin.site.register(model, Admin)

    return model
```

Please refer this image for reference:

[image]

Here the model **Test 11** is created by dynamic model method, I am not able to access that model, **Add/Change** Button also not there and when I kill the server and restart it , that dynamically created model gets hide.

How can I access this model? Did I miss any steps here or what's wrong in it?

Comment: As I know, when django app starting, it caching all ModelAdmin actions. You need tracing django app init logic and caching or restart Django app, when new model created.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but a few lines of code solved it. You are going to need to register your dynamic models and then reload and clear your cache. It will look something like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.core.urlresolvers import clear_url_caches
from django.utils.module_loading import import_module

admin.site.register(model, admin_options)
reload(import_module(settings.ROOT_URLCONF))
clear_url_caches()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Let me check and revert you back.